# SQL: add string to field when other value changes

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have 2 columns (ColA, ColB) both are datatype Nvarchar.
I need col B to be unique for the values in ColA

Some rows have 2 different values in ColA with the same value (non-unique) in ColB.

I want to write a query to display the ColB values along with the letter "D" (as duplicate) at the end, where the value in ColA is changing to something else.

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer? What do you mean with the value changing in ColA?

Comment: Can you provide sample table data?

Comment: You can have either a *read* query (select), or *write* query (update), but not both. Your question suggests you want a query to do both, which you can't have.

Comment: @Bohemian, it's obviously a *read* query as he states "a query to **display**". Displaying is read, no?

Comment: somthing like this: `select Campaign,destUrl,destUrl+'D'
from Table1
where ...` the WHERE is the hard part. and i dont want to update.

Comment: Again: please provide sample data and the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can understand, you want to mark the rows where the ColB value needs to be changed.

If so try something like this

```
SELECT t1.COLA, 
       t1.COLB + 'D' 
FROM   TABLE1 t1 
       INNER JOIN TABLE1 t2 
               ON t1.COLB = t2.COLB 
                  AND t1.COLA != t2.COLA
```

This will only show the "double" rows. If you want to show all the rows, just add a UNION to the end:

```
SELECT t1.COLA, 
       t1.COLB + 'D' 
FROM   TABLE1 t1 
       INNER JOIN TABLE1 t2 
               ON t1.COLB = t2.COLB 
                  AND t1.COLA != t2.COLA 
UNION 
SELECT * 
FROM   TABLE1 
WHERE  COLA NOT IN (SELECT t1.COLA 
                    FROM   TABLE1 t1 
                           INNER JOIN TABLE1 t2 
                                   ON t1.COLB = t2.COLB 
                                      AND t1.COLA != t2.COLA)
```

See the full example at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ff8bd1/12).

Comment: it looks great! but when i run the both together with the UNION i get this: "All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists." and I'm mot sure what is wrong

Comment: When using a UNION you have to make sure both sides of the UNION have the same columns!   
Set up your query in SQL Fiddle or post it here and I'll take a look at it.